# Saving OS X Spaces/Desktops

Tags: macos, desktop, spaces

For how I use my laptop, it would be extremely helpful to be able to use Spaces/Desktops in OS X to break up different projects. One project may have a couple of websites/URLs, a pdf and a spreadsheet. It would be very useful to be able to put these in a space, eg have a browser window with tabs for each site that's related the project, the local files, and anything else that's related (maybe an email, document, etc.), close the Space and then open it later as needed.

Is there a way to save Spaces/Desktops like this so that all files, browser tabs, etc. can be reopened at once by "opening" the Space/Desktop?

I am running Mavericks.

Answer (score 5):

I use Yosemite but here can be found how to utilize in Mavericks:http://www.t-gaap.com/2013/10/29/managing-spaces-in-os-x-mavericks[enter link description here](http://www.t-gaap.com/2013/10/29/managing-spaces-in-os-x-mavericks)

In Preferences check the Automatically Add box
[image]

Add several, I have 9 spaces I switch between in Yosemite:
[image]

You add a space by moving your cursor to the top right hot corner of your desktop and clicking the + sign.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no.

You can assign an app to a space, but not a 'project', as such.
Re-opening any app would at best reopen your last working session on that app.

Closest you could get would be to keep all documents for that project in a single folder & select all, right-click/Open. Each would open to its last-assigned Space, last-assigned window placement.
This wouldn't work for email etc, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do it, but there are a few third-party applications around that may get you at least some of the way there, such as [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) and [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/).